# Connect with PuTTY client to EC2 service?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, putty, private-key

How to connect with SSH client to EC2 service ?

I have the `.pem` file with `*.ppk` extension and structure:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: imported-openssh-key
Public-Lines: 6
KEY ^ LINES
Private-Lines: 14
KEY LINES
Private-MAC: KEY
```

I have Putty
http://s017.radikal.ru/i400/1411/46/f11ad26d87e0.png

Do I have to upload this file in PuTTY?

But how to make it... PuTTY has no Open File dialog... What is the way ?

The common way of using PuTTY is in  Host Name (or IP address) field to enter domain name.
For EC2 service that is Public IP I suppose.
I enter this value and have console opened, it propose to enter login...
I have no login, except from login to enter to EC2

--- my answer:
Hi, Thanks I found how attach .pkk file , but opened console again demands for login.
Also where to enter username as you wrote

> after you specify your EC2 hostname and username

?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to convert pem file to ppk by using puttygen, so after you will that ppk file use it under ssh auth give that file location and in hostname give ec2 instance name, it will allow you to login, user-name give ec2-user name if you are using linux, or check for the user-name according to your OS.

Answer (score 0):

On the initial PuTTY *Configuration* window (after you specify your EC2 hostname and username), go to the *Connection > SSH > Auth* page and specify your `.ppk` key file in the *Private key file for authentication* box.

For more details, see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

I'm assuming you have obtained the `.ppk` file by converting the `.pem` file downloaded when creating EC2 instance. You do not need to "upload" such `.ppk` file (or actually it's public part) anywhere as this is done automatically, when creating the EC2 instance. Had you generated the `.ppk` yourself, it's a different story.

*Note that this it is NOT the `.pem` file with the `.ppk` extension. It's the `.ppk` file. It has nothing to do with the `.pem` anymore after converting.*